# Extract ZIP file in specific folder on server using terminal?

Tags: server, terminal, cpanel, unzip

I have a problem with my VPS server, more precisely with extracting a .zip file (5GB) through the file manager. I have limited support because it is a self-managed VPS. I need a command for a terminal to extract file "5.zip" to a specific server dir for ex: http:xxxxxxx.com/funny folder on my server. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You provide URL, not path to directory. But to extract `zip` file in particular directory you can use command:

```
cd /directory/funny
unzip /path/to/5.zip
```

Change `/directory/funny` with the real directory which your web service serve.